# Win 10 path variable is screwed

Tags: python-3.x, windows, path

I was trying to add selenium to my PATH by using this command  `setx path "%path%;c:\directoryPath"` and now commands such as `python` and `pip install ...` gives back this

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

when it wasn't doing so before the command.

How do I fix/revert this? How do I add selenium.exe to my win 10 path?

edit: results of `echo $PATH`

```
PS C:\prog\react> echo $PATH
PS C:\prog\react>
```

and a screenshot of my environment variables
[image: enviroment variables]

Comment: Please post the contents of PATH (as text).

Comment: i tried echo $PATH and it gave nothing @ack

Comment: Use `path` to display the contents of the PATH variable. `help path` shows help. Use Copy/Paste to post the result as text, not as an image - see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)